# Is there an easier way to manipulate the index of a pandas DataFrame into and out of columns without DataFrame.reset_index()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Looking for some short and easy way to change indexes with columns. To setup an example

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
n = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, n ** 2).reshape((n, n)))
df.columns = [f'c{i}' for i in range(n)]
df = df.set_index(['c0', 'c1', 'c2'])
print(df)

          c3  c4
c0 c1 c2        
0  1  2    3   4
5  6  7    8   9
10 11 12  13  14
15 16 17  18  19
20 21 22  23  24
```

now to change the index, for simple cases

```
# instead of this (long)
df.reset_index().set_index(['c3', 'c4'])

# I want something like this (shorter)
df.change_index(['c3', 'c4'])
```

and for more complicated cases

```
# instead of this (long and verbose)
names = list(df.index.names) 
names[names.index('c1')] = 'c3'
df.reset_index().set_index(names)

# something like this
df.change_index('c1', 'c3')
```

add index

```
# instead of 
names = list(df.index.names)
names.append('c3')
df.reset_index().set_index(names)

# something like this
df.add_index('c3')
```

remove index

```
# instead of 
names = list(df.index.names)
names.remove('c1')
df.reset_index().set_index(names)

# something like this
df.remove_index('c1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your own dataframe method like this.

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

def change_index(df, index=None):
    if index:
        return df.reset_index(drop=True).set_index(index)
    return df

PandasObject.change_index = change_index
```

then you can call this method on your dataframe

```
df.change_index(['c0', 'c3'])

       c0  c2  c4
c1 c3            
1  3    0   2   4
6  8    5   7   9
11 13  10  12  14
16 18  15  17  19
21 23  20  22  24
```

Comment: isn't it a bit sketchy to modify modules like this? like, what if there are name collisions in the future?

Comment: highly unlikely that pandas will interduce method with similar name as change_index in future, but yes you have to be precautious.

Comment: please accept the answer if it solves your problem. thanks!

Comment: I would remove the `drop=True`, but I can't seem to edit